# Doubt in theory of Logarithmic differentiation of generating functions from Apostol

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, analytic-number-theory

While self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol introduction to analytic number theory I have following doubt in section 14.10 .

I am adding it's image highlighting the part in which I have doubt.

[image]

> My doubt is - how $ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} G'_A (x^m) x^m $ = $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn} $ .
>
> I think there should be a additional term $x^{mn+m} $ on RHS as  x × $G'_A(x) = \sum_{n \epsilon A} f(n) x^n  $  and then I have to put x = $x^m $ and then multiply by $x^m $ .

Can somebody please explain where I had made a mistake.

Comment: "how is $G'_A (x^m) x^m  = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn} $". It isn't. It's $\sum_{m=1}^\infty G'_A (x^m) x^m  = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn} $.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown yes that was a mistake, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your expression, i.e., where you multiplied both sides of the expression for $G'_A(x)$ by $x$, you could replace *all* $x$ with $x^m$ to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x\left(G'_A(x)\right) & = \sum_{n \epsilon A} f(n) x^n \\
x^m\left(G'_A(x^m)\right) & = \sum_{n \epsilon A} f(n) \left(x^m\right)^n \\
G'_A(x^m)x^m & = \sum_{n \epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Alternatively, you could do the substitution first and then the multiplication, with this, showing it in detail, resulting in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
G_A(x) & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} \frac{f(n)}{n} x^{n} \\
G'_A(x) & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{n-1} \\
G'_A(x^m) & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) \left(x^m\right)^{n-1} \\
G'_A(x^m) & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn - m} \\
G'_A(x^m)x^m & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn - m}x^m \\
G'_A(x^m)x^m & = \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

In either case, taking the sum from $m = 1$ to $\infty$ of both sides gives the part you're asking about, i.e,.

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} G'_A(x^m)x^m = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n\epsilon A} f(n) x^{mn} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$